# Nativescript webview and android back button

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, webview, nativescript

I have a made a page in nativescript that only containes a webview. Here is my code:

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" actionBarHidden="true">

    <WebView src="http://example.com/" />

</Page>
```

And here is the JS:

```
import * as webViewModule from "tns-core-modules/ui/web-view";

let webView = new webViewModule.WebView();

webView.on(webViewModule.WebView.loadFinishedEvent, function (args: webViewModule.LoadEventData) {
    let message;
    if (!args.error) {
        message = "WebView finished loading " + args.url;
    }
    else {
        message = "Error loading " + args.url + ": " + args.error;
    }

});
webView.src = "http://example.com/";
```

Everything is working great until I press the android back button. Then inside of navigating to the last page inside the webview, the app just exists.
When I open it again from the applications menu (returning to the same minimized app) it reloads the webview content and not saving it's state.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

You need to handle Android hard button like this:

First import dependencies :

```
import { AndroidApplication, AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData } from "application";
import * as application from "application";
```

Then add this code :

```
application.android.on(AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, (data: AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData) => {
  data.cancel = true; // prevents default back button behavior
  console.log("webview can go back " + webView.canGoBack);
  if (webView.canGoBack) //if webview can go back
      webView.goBack();
  else
      this.router.backToPreviousPage();
});
```

Comment: what abou iOS ?

Comment: iOS doesn't have hard back button. So no worry :)

Comment: but will the "soft" back button appear automatically when you navigate ?, am asking that because am working on an app where i needed to disable the action bar.

Comment: That you can handle. You can hide action bar.

Comment: Hi Amit or Deepika  ,Can you add code on how to handle(hide) action bar on ios

Comment: and also for html page, if you want action bar but no back button in iOS : <NavigationButton *ngIf="!isAndroidFlag" visibility="collapsed"></NavigationButton>

Comment: I think you have an error in your code (I'm using it in `onWebViewLoaded` event), the console.log is using `this.webView` instead of just `webView`.