# How to enable the Back button when using WebView in Nativescript-Vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am a nativescript-vue novice developer.
I am currently implementing the Android side code and I succeeded in inserting WebView.
However, if I touched the back physical button on my phone, the app was terminated immediately.
When I use WebView in Nativescript-Vue, when I touch the back button, I want to know how to go back without ending.

I tried the following link. However, an error occurs.
[Nativescript webview and android back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646999/nativescript-webview-and-android-back-button)

Is it different from NativeScript code and NativeScript Vue code?
I do not even notice the difference between the two above. Please help me.

/app/components/App.vue

```html
<template>
    <Page actionBarHidden="true">
        <FlexboxLayout>
            <WebView src="http://example.com" />
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script >

</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

/app/main.js

```js
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue'
import App from './components/App'
import VueDevtools from 'nativescript-vue-devtools'
import { AndroidApplication, AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData } from "application";
import * as application from "application";
import {WebView} from "tns-core-modules/ui/web-view";
var webView = new WebView();
application.android.on(AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, (AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData) => {
  AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData.cancel = true; // prevents default back button behavior
  webView.canGoBack = true;
  console.log('back')

  // console.log("webview can go back "+this.webView.canGoBack);
  // if (webView.canGoBack) //if webview can go back
  //   webView.goBack();
  // else
  //   this.router.backToPreviousPage();
});

if(TNS_ENV !== 'production') {
  Vue.use(VueDevtools)
}

// Prints Vue logs when --env.production is *NOT* set while building
Vue.config.silent = (TNS_ENV === 'production')

new Vue({
  render: h => h('frame', [h(App)])
}).$start()
```

Error Message

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onBackPressed failed

TypeError: Cannot set property canGoBack of [object Object] which has only a getter
File: "file:///data/data/io.bagstation.bagstation/files/app/bundle.js, line: 375, column: 20

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'module.exports../main.js.application__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.android.on.AndroidActivityBackPressedEventData', file:'file:///data/data/io.bagstation.bagstation/files/app/bundle.js', line: 375, column: 21
    Frame: function:'Observable.notify', file:'file:///data/data/io.bagstation.bagstation/files/app/vendor.js', line: 41320, column: 15
    Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onBackPressed', file:'file:///data/data/io.bagstation.bagstation/files/app/vendor.js', line: 63019, column: 25
    Frame: function:'NativeScriptActivity.onBackPressed', file:'file:///data/data/io.bagstation.bagstation/files/app/vendor.js', line: 60331, column: 21


    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1116)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:996)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:983)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onBackPressed(NativeScriptActivity.java:50)
    at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:3049)
    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2723)
    at android.support.v4.view.KeyEventDispatcher.activitySuperDispatchKeyEventPre28(KeyEventDispatcher.java:137)
    at android.support.v4.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:87)
    at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:126)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:535)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2533)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:357)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4798)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4670)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4205)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4224)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4232)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4408)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4205)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4224)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4232)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4205)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4224)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4384)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4552)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2454)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2017)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2008)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2431)
    at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6650)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:818)
```

I do not know where to put my file if you just write the code.
I would appreciate it if you write the file name together!

Comment: There won't be any difference in the code for Vue, except you will `goBack` on your frame instead of `router.backToPreviousPage();` which is specific to Angular.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I tried the following link.[Nativescript webview and android back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646999/nativescript-webview-and-android-back-button)
However, an error occurs.
I modified the code I tried and changed the question.

Comment: @SengAm Did you solve this issue? I'm also facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an absolutely identical problem and could not solve it for a long time. + Everything is absolutely not written anywhere (at least I did not find it) how to access native components, bypassing vue components. In particular through ref.

Perhaps my version has a crutch in itself. But he works.

**webpack.config.js** In it, I added an alias to nativescript core. Don't ask, I don't understand why this works. And why if I don't make this alias - it won't work. It's like some kind of magic.

```
const webpack = require("@nativescript/webpack");

module.exports = (env) => {
webpack.init(env);

webpack.chainWebpack(config => {
    config.resolve.alias.set('tns-core-modules', '@nativescript/core')
})

return webpack.resolveConfig();
};
```

in AndroidManifest.xml in the application section, I added **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"** - this is necessary so that the webview can access resources that are not https

well, the only thing left is to add one small detail to the vue component

```
<template>
  <Page actionBarHidden="true">
    <GridLayout>
      <WebView ref="test" src="paste link here or in vars "/>
    </GridLayout>
  </Page>
</template>

<script>
const application = require("tns-core-modules/application");


export default {
  computed: {
    message() {
      return "Blank {N}-Vue app";
    },

  },

  mounted() {
    let self = this
    application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, function (args) {
      console.log("Event: " + args.eventName + ", Activity: " + args.activity);
      args.cancel = true; // to cancel back navigation and do something custom.
      if (self.$refs.test.nativeView.canGoBack) //if webview can go back
        self.$refs.test.nativeView.goBack();

    });
  }
```

well, that's pretty much all I did.